# Cannot start nuxt: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost

Tags: nuxtjs3

I need some help

I'm trying to start nuxt3 project but have a trouble to start it.

[image: error messages]

and also got this messages.
`[get-port] Unable to find an available port (tried 3000-3100 on host "0.0.0.0"). Using alternative port 3000`

First, I think the problem is /etc/hosts file but it looks good.

I really need your help you guys. Thanks!

[Nuxt project]
mac os
nuxt 3.4
node 18
npm 10

[etc/hosts]
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

nuxt3 project
and idk what this error messages stands for

Comment: Have you installed the dependecies? Also, what do you use to run the thing `pnpm dev`?